# M1 Pro macOS 12.3 nothing provides ncurses >=6.2,<6.3.0a0 needed by readline-8.1-hedafd6a_0

Tags: anaconda, apple-m1

M1 Pro macOS 12.3 can't install lastest `Miniforge3==4.11.0-4`.I wanted to install Anaconda on my Macbook, but anaconda doesn't have an ARM64 version. I followed the instructions to install MiniForge and then encountered this problem, which made it impossible to continue the installation. There isn't a lot of information in the community about this bug, so I don't know what to do next.

```
$ bash ./Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh

Welcome to Miniforge3 4.11.0-4
.
.
.
.

  - nothing provides ncurses >=6.2,<6.3.0a0 needed by readline-8.1-hedafd6a_0
  - nothing provides ncurses >=6.2,<6.3.0a0 needed by readline-8.1-hedafd6a_0

The environment can't be solved, aborting the operation
error    Could not solve for environment specs
critical UnsatisfiableError
```

and `ncurses == 6.3.0`  has been installed.

```
$ brew info ncurses 
ncurses: stable 6.3 (bottled) [keg-only]
```